# How to remove logout timer in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I accidentally set timer to log me out of phpmyadmin to 0. Now when i log in, it logs me out immediately. I purged phpmyadmin, and after i reinstalled it, it still does the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find `config.inc.php` where you install phpMyAdmin. There will be a

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 0;
```

Change the 0 to another number (example: 1 second) and save the file.

---

- `config.inc.php` file is not required, and is only for custom configurations, phpmyadmin will first refer to `./libraries/config.default.php` but please do not edit that file. Create the 1st file.
- `config.sample.inc.php` can be used to create the initial template for `config.inc.php`.

Comment: Many sites reference this file (config.inc.php) but it doesn't exist on my system.  This doesn't help me.

Comment: @UserX Have you checked `/etc/phpmyadmin`?

Comment: @UserX it is an optional file we use to create custom configs. If you do not have it you also will not have set a timer to log out ;-)

Comment: In my case the config file was in libraries/config.default.php (using v5.1). I changed LoginCookieValidity value to 3600*24 (24 hours).